# Correct "config.ssh.shell" value for vagrant windows box?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm starting vagrant box with Windows 7 from host which is also Windows 7 with "vagrant up" command.

Contents of Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "win7_base_test"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 88, host: 3088
  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
  config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
  config.ssh.port = "3088"
  config.ssh.host = "127.0.0.1"
  config.ssh.shell = "cmd"
end
```

As a result I get following listing with an error at the end:

```
vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 88 => 3088 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:3088
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
The configured shell (config.ssh.shell) is invalid and unable
to properly execute commands. The most common cause for this is
using a shell that is unavailable on the system. Please verify
you're using the full path to the shell and that the shell is
executable by the SSH user.
```

Notice: I'm able to connect to vagrant box by executing "vagrant ssh" in the meantime and issue shell commands there.

Therefore I have a question: do I use the correct value ("cmd") for "config.ssh.shell" parameter? What values are possible there at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use WinRM instead of SSH: set `config.vm.communicator` to "winrm".

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html), `config.ssh.shell` only affects what shell is used *within* Vagrant, not what is used as the shell when you perform `vagrant ssh`.  By default it uses bash, and unless you have a specific need to change this then leave it as that I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

Use the config.ssh.shell = "powershell" instead of config.ssh.shell = "cmd"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I had "The configured shell (config.ssh.shell) is invalid..." error after having deleted the vagrant box used for machine creating.

I restored the box and everything worked fine then.